# How to Pass Parameter to Frameset Using ASP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have an ASP page called map.asp and in it I have a dynamically generated table with links to detailed node and utilization information.  However, I need to pass this information to a frameset.  It currently is code like this:

```
<a href='gauge-frame.asp?nodeid=<%response.write rsnetdevices("nodeid")%>'
```

where gauge-frame.asp looks like this:

```
<frame src="details.asp?nodeid=<%response.write rsnetdevices("nodeid")%>">
```

However, I'm getting a "Page cannot be displayed error".

Suggestions on how to fix are appreciated.

Dale

============================

Below is maptest.asp

```
<%
Option Explicit
Dim rsSolarWinds, conn,  rsnetdevices, nodeid
nodeid = Request.QueryString("nodeid")
set Conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set rsSolarWinds = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Conn.open "Provider=sqloledb;Server="";Initial Catalog=Skynet;

set rsnetdevices = conn.Execute ("SELECT Caption AS NodeName, nodeid, category,  substring(statusdescription, 16,4) as nodedown " _
& " from nodes " _
& " where category = 'Infrastructure' or caption like '%intswt%' or caption like '%intrtr%') " )

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<table class="gradienttable" cellspacing="0" border>
<tr>
<th colspan=4 style="font-size:7.5pt"; "font:small Verdana,Sans-serif";"font-family:Verdana" align="center">Network Devices</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<th style="font-size:7.5pt"; "font:small Verdana,Sans-serif";"font-family:Verdana" align="center">Node ID</th>
<th style="font-size:7.5pt"; "font:small Verdana,Sans-serif";"font-family:Verdana" align="center">Node Name</th>
<th style="font-size:7.5pt"; "font:small Verdana,Sans-serif";"font-family:Verdana" align="center">Node Status</th>
</tr>

    <%do while not rsnetdevices.EOF%></do>
    <tr>

        <td width=8 style="font-size:7.5pt"; "font:small Verdana,Sans-serif";"font-family:Verdana" align="center">
        <a href='gauge-frame.asp?nodeid=<%response.write rsnetdevices("nodeid")%>'  target="_blank" title="Show Node Details")><%response.write rsnetdevices("nodeid")%></a>
        </td>


        <%rsnetdevices.MoveNext%>
        <%loop%>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

And below is frame-gauge.asp

```
<%
Option Explicit
Dim rsnetdevices, conn, nodeid
nodeid = Request.QueryString("nodeid")
set Conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set rsnetdevices = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Conn.open "Provider=sqloledb;Server="";Initial Catalog=Skynet;"

set rsnetdevices = conn.Execute ("SELECT description, sysname, machinetype, type, devicerole,  cpuload, substring(statusdescription, 16,4) as nodedown, substring(statusdescription, 16,2) as nodeup,  " _
& " ip_address,  dns,  nextpoll, location, unmanaged, percentmemoryused, contact, lastboot, iosversion, cpucount, substring(description, 77, 53) as software   " _
& " FROM Nodes "  _
& " where Nodes.Nodeid = '" &nodeid  & "' " )


%>

<html>
<head>
<Title>Network Device Information</title>

<frameset cols="48%,52%" frameborder="0">
    <frame src="gauges.asp" scrolling="NO" marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 >
    <frame src="details.asp?nodeid=<%response.write rsnetdevices("nodeid")%>">
</frameset>

</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look into [<%: %> Syntax for HTML Encoding Output](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2). It might be that you have to reference your variable differently, like `src="details.asp?nodeid=<%= rsnetdevices("nodeid")%>"` or something. I'd recommend changing all `href` and `src` references to `#` or empty space respectively & writing the variable you're trying to access to the page in a `<div>` to ensure you're getting an output before referencing it in a `href` or `src`. I dont' think you'll need to use `response.write`.

Comment: If you are able to supply the relevant full code for the front end and backend, that might help me decide which reference format you need to use, i.e. `<%=` or <%:`

Comment: @AlexanderNied This code is ASP Classic, not ASP.NET. They are very different. I have amended the tag you added.

Comment: @ADyson - thanks, sorry about that-- I should have probably just waited for someone with more knowledge of ASP to handle that.  My bad, thanks for fixing that.

Comment: I tried adding the ASP Classic tag but I didn't have enough "points".

Comment: @dalezjc you don’t need to add it, it already exists as `asp-classic`. A privilege is required to add new tags so you must have typed it incorrectly.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I tried to add it when I first created the question.

Comment: There is no `nodeid` in the select list of the sql query in gauge-frame.asp (or is it frame-gauge.asp?), so there won't be an item called "nodeid" in the opened recordset (`rsnetdevices`). Either add `nodeid` to the select list, or use the nodeid from the querystring directly in the link.. `<frame src="details.asp?nodeid=<%response.write nodeid%>">` or simply: `<frame src="details.asp?nodeid=<%=nodeid%>">`

Comment: On IIS disable the "Show Friendly Messages" feature. Or use chrome. This should give you the actual line where the error is happening

Answer (score 1):

@SearchAndResQ was correct in that nodeid was missing in the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

I see an extra closing parenthesis at the end of the SQL in this section:

```
set rsnetdevices = conn.Execute ("SELECT Caption AS NodeName, nodeid, category,  substring(statusdescription, 16,4) as nodedown " _
& " from nodes " _
& " where category = 'Infrastructure' or caption like '%intswt%' or caption like '%intrtr%') " )
```

As ullfindsmit commented, you need to disable the "Show Friendly Messages" misfeature in IIS, so it'll give you the actual line number and error message, not the totally useless and infuriating "page couldn't be displayed" message.